# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running JUnit

Tags: junit4

Hi i am getting this error please help me out, thanks

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ge/energy/wp/core/exception/WPException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class`enter code here`.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.hasSuiteMethod(ClassRequest.java:62)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunnerClass(ClassRequest.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:445)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ge.energy.wp.core.exception.WPException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
... 15 more
```

Comment: Which version of java? You changed the java version to an older one?

Answer (score 0):

try adding source folder to your classpath. If you use eclipse, right click test file and select Run configuration under Junit test and select classpath and add your source folders to class path.

Answer (score 0):

Check **class** WPException. Usually your IDE should show you if something is wrong with the java file but not with the class file - either it wasn't compiled or missing (the error is triggered when the JVM can't find the class) for some other reason, one of them could be, like bluelabel mentioned, a problem with the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post...but may help someone else...

whenever I have faced this issue only problem have been the java version eclipse is defaulted to - which is the eclipse jre.

Fix - change to the proper jre installed on your machine !

Comment: Consider adding some details to improve your answer.